# Show that $X^n-1$ has no repeated irreducible factors over $\mathbb{F}_q$ if and only if $gcd(q,n)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to prove that $X^n-1$ has no repeated irreducible factors over $\mathbb{F}_q$ if and only if $gcd(q,n)=1$. So far I've completed one implication: If $gcd(q,n) \neq 1$, then $n=p^em$ for some $e>0, p \nmid m$. The Frobenius yields $X^n-1=X^{mp^e}-1=(X^m-1)^{p^e}$ which obviously has repeated irreducible factors.

However, I'm stuck on the other implication. I know that $f \in \mathbb{F}_q[X]$ has no repeated factors if and only if $gcd(f,f')=1$ where $f'$ is the formal derivative of $f$. But I do not know how I could apply this for $X^n-1$ and its formal derivative $nX^{n-1}$. Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\gcd(n,p)=1$.

Let $I$ be the ideal of $F_q[X]$ generated by $X^n-1,nX^{n-1}$.

From $\gcd(n,p)=1$, it follows that $n$, when regarded as an element of $F_q$, is a unit, hence
\begin{align*}
&
nX^{n-1}\in I
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
X^{n-1}\in I
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
X^n\in I
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
X^n-(X^n-1)\in I
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
1\in I
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
I=(1)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so in $F_q[X]$, we have $\gcd(X^n-1,nX^{n-1})=1$.

Here's another way . . .

Suppose $\gcd(n,p)=1$, and suppose $X^n-1$ and $nX^{n-1}$ have a nonunit common factor in $F_q[X]$.

Then $n$ is a unit, when regarded as an element of $F_q$, and $n > 1$, when regarded as an element of $\mathbb{Z}$.

But then since $F_q[X]$ is a UFD, it follows that $X^n-1$ and $nX^{n-1}$ must have a common prime factor, contradiction, since the only prime factor of $nX^{n-1}$ is $X$, which is not a factor of $X^n-1$.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you! Do I understand it correctly that regarding $n$ as an element of $F_q$ simply means regarding it as $n$ $mod p$ in the field $F_p$?

Comment: Yes, when regarding $n$ as an element of $F_q$, we just mean $n=1+\cdots + 1$.